# Is $T \colon \left( W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^2} \right) \longrightarrow \left( L^2(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^2} \right)$ unbounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am currently considering the following operator ("modified Laplacian"):

$$T \colon \left( W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^2} \right) \longrightarrow \left( L^2(\mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{L^2} \right)$$

definied by
$$u \mapsto Tu := -u^{\prime \prime}$$

Of course $-u^{\prime \prime}$ refers to the second weak-derivative of $u$.

Please note, that I have equipped the domain of the operator with the $\| \cdot \|_{L^2}$-Norm (the operator would clearly be bounded, when considering the Sobolev-Norm)!

Is this operator an **unbounded** one? I have picked an arbitrary $f \in W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: As for the actual question, try something like $\sin nx$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\sin(nx)|^2 dx$ does not converge, i.e. the function is not square-integrable. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I didn't see that you are on $\mathbb R$. An obvious modification will work: $f_n=\sin nx/(1+x^2)$

Comment: This seems to work... Although the necessary computations are quite painful. I was looking for a simple result, such that the unboundedness can be easily shown in one ore two lines, without much computational-work.

Answer (score 2):

An easy method is to use the Fourier transform,
$$
      f_{n} = (\chi_{[n,n+1]})^{\wedge}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{isx}ds.
$$
By Parseval's identity, $\|f_{n}\|=\|\chi_{[n,n+1]}\|=1$. And,
$$
             Tf_{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{isx}s^{2}ds, \\
              \|Tf_{n}\|=\|s^{2}\chi_{[n,n+1]}(s)\| \ge n^{2}.
$$
This gets to core of the issue, too, because the unbounded spectrum forces $T$ to be unbounded.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I was just trying to verify, that $f_n \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and struggled:  
$\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R} | f_n(x) |^2 dx = \int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_n^{n+1} e^{isx} ds \right|^2 dx \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb R} \int_n^{n+1} |e^{isx}|^2 ds dx = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb R} 1 dx = \infty$.
Do you have a working suggestion to show this?

Comment: Another remark: Is $f_n^\prime$ continuos?
If a function $u$ is in $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$, then $u^\prime$ is in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)$, which is a subset of $C^0(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: $f_{n}$ is infinitely differentiable. $f_{n} = (\chi_{[n,n+1]})^{\vee}(x)$, and $\frac{d^{k}f_n}{dx^{k}}=((is)^{k}\chi_{[n,n+1]})^{\vee}(x)$. Every derivative of $f_n$ is in $L^{2}$. You can write the function directly as well: $f_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{i(n+1)x}-e^{inx}}{ix}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{i(n+1/2)x} \frac{\sin (x/2)}{x}$.

Comment: I know that for any $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$ it holds $\mathscr F f \in C_0(\mathbb R)$. How did you conclude that the Fourier transform was infinitely often differentiable?

Comment: @KennyH : The simplest answer is that $\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{isx}ds$ is an integral over a finite interval; so differentiating with respect to $x$ as many times as you want can be interchanged with the integral, and there are no convergence issues. From the point of view of spectral theory, the integral represents a continuous sum (with uniform weight) of the generalized eigenfunctions of differentiation, with eigenvalue 's' in the interval $[n,n+1]$. Eigenfunctions of differentiation are infinitely differentiable and so are continuous sums of such over finite ranges of the eigenvalue parameter s.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for a short proof without computational work, here is an alternative solution:

It is well-known (and possibly trivial, depending on your definition) that $W^{2,2}(\mathbb R)$ is complete in the operator norm $\|u\|^2=\|u\|_{L^2}^2+\|u''\|_{L^2}^2$. Hence $T$ is a closed operator.

On the other hand, $W^{2,2}$ is not closed in $L^2$, so $T$ cannot be bounded.